# Continuous request with jQuery

Tags: jquery, request, meebo

After using Meebo I noticed that they had a nice little system for continually getting information from the server. They have 1 single request running, and they continually monitor the response as it's "loading".

I was wondering if there was a way to do this with jQuery. If not, can someone give me some recommendations on where to start doing this in plain Javascript?

Thanks in advance

(P.S. because I know someone's gonna say it - I'm aware of the backend problems this could introduce and I believe have the correct knowledge to prevent against it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For jQuery over XMPP/BOSH I use:  http://github.com/ssoper/jquery-bosh

Comet and BOSH are two technologies that fill the same void.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the comet plug-in, it should help you accomplish that: [Comet](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Comet)

Answer (score 0):

Comet will works better if you have dedicated web-server for it. BOSH is the same.

Get a look to Comet-server APE. Read http://www.ape-project.org/ajax-push.html
And after it choose any Comet/BOSH software especially for your needs. Good luck)